# Deezer: Artists top songs and Rank

Tags: deezer

The TOP method:

```
http://developers.deezer.com/api/artist/top
```

retrieve the top tracks for each artist; I know that the answer is country-related; is it possible to have a "global" top? Which is the date range taken into consideration for the answer?

I expected, from the TOP answer, decreasing (or increasing, depending on the order) RANK, but from this query

```
http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/2276/top?output=xml&limit=20
```

I can see, for the first three results, the following ranks:

1) 425272

2) 434667

3) 401878

Is the order of "rank" different than top? Maybe the date range is different?

Answer (score 2):

The rank is a global indicator of a song's popularity on DEezer, who goes from 0 to 1M. The closer to 1M, the most popular the track is. The rank is updated daily based on all the Deezer users' streams.

Comment: Ok, but why the rank is different respect to the TOP chart?
Is it because TOP is country-based and RANK is worlwide-based?
The date range is the same?

Comment: Rank is worlwide based.