# Using deezer api, is it possible to get the more popular songs?

Tags: deezer

Using deezer api, is it possible to get the more popular songs? I saw a rank attribute on the tracks but didn't see in the search api a way to specify a minimum rank or sthg like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is that: http://developers.deezer.com/api/editorial/charts

Comment: I have one more question, what represent the property "rank" on a track? Is it a ranking based on popularity?

Comment: ok I found an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485467/deezer-artists-top-songs-and-rank